# AWS Elastic Beanstalk single instance status issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

elastic beanstalk env dashboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nAoL.png)

aws cloudshell "eb health" result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVmtB.png)

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB) Single Instance for my deployment. When I deploy my application, it gets deployed to the EC2 instance and runs successfully. However, on the EB Dashboard, the status is shown as "grey." I am wondering why this is happening.

Despite the successful deployment, the status on the EB Dashboard remains grey.

I read in the official AWS documentation that health checks based on HTTP requests are performed only when using a Load Balancer, and for Single Instances, it relies on the EC2 instance's status. However, the documentation stops there without further explanation.

How can I make the dashboard show a green status light?

How can I make the dashboard show a green status light?